# Is there a way to track Facebook Campaign Ad Installs with Expo managed workflow?

Tags: expo, branch.io, android-facebook, idfa, facebook-ads

Stack: Expo React Native, expo-branch

I am searching for a way to track Facebook Campaign Ad Installs with **Expo** in the **managed workflow**. I have integrated expo-branch (link below) and set up the integration between Facebook Ad Manager and Branch. As it stands, Branch is not getting the IDFA, which I suspect is the reason I am getting no analytics on Facebook through any ad campaigns. It looks like Expo has restricted access to the IDFA and I'm wondering if anybody has found a viable workaround (without detaching from Expo).

References:

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/branch/

https://forums.expo.io/t/latest-expo-branch-excluding-the-idfa-code/44357

Answer (score 0):

A Branchster here:

For [SAN](https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/self-attributing-networks-sans)(self attributing networks) like Google and Facebook, it is necessary that the Branch SDK correctly captures the device identifiers for the SAN integration to work and you be able to see attributed Installs and downstream events. Since there is not much support for Expo in the managed workflow, we would suggest using Bare workflow. Alternatively, you can reference our complete SDK support [here](https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/android-sdk-overview).